# order by and case with mixed column datatype

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

we need to use order by with a case clause as the user may choose the type of order from the dropdown .. the situation seemed ok until a column with integer value wa also introduced.. it seems that for some reason, MYSQL is also assuming the integer column to be a string and ordering likewise ..

below is the order by clause

```
 order by (case when p_SortBy = 'Default' then CONVERT(st.IncrementNo, unsigned)
  WHEN  p_SortBy ='Program'
    THEN st.StudyProgram 
    WHEN p_SortBy = 'Student'
    then st.Name
    when p_SortBy = 'Mobile'
    then st.Mobile

  END) asc
```

the first case (Default) is for an integer value but it is sorting like so 
`105,106,107,108,109,11,110`

any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use multiple `CASE`:

```
order by 
  case when p_SortBy = 'Default'  then CONVERT(st.IncrementNo, unsigned) END,
  case when p_SortBy = 'Program'  then st.StudyProgram END,
  case when p_SortBy = 'Student'  then st.Name END,
  case when p_SortBy = 'Mobile'   then st.Mobile END
```